# how to pass data from one page to another in oracle form builder using sql/plsql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

Suppose i have a registration form for a hostel which consists of 1)Guardian details 2)Student details 3)Room details and when i have filled the 1st part, i click next and it takes me to the 2nd part and after filling 2nd part, i click next to go to the room details part and after that i click save.

so my question is "how to pass data from one page to another in oracle form builder using sql/plsql and to save all information at the same time in different tables?"

Comment: Oracle Form Builder allows creating forms known as blocks which are based on database tables or views, which means blocks are bound with the database tables. Based on the block you can refer block_name.item_name if you want to pass information from one block to another block.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/forms/FormsMasterDetail/FormsMasterDetailOBE.htm), there are many more tutorials on how to create forms using Oracle Forms Builder.

Comment: Do you mean transfer data between pages or between different form applications?

Comment: @user75ponic thank you a lot. you've been really helpful.

Comment: @nightfox79 its transferring data between pages.